# Error deploying chaincode to Hyperledger Fabric 2 test-network (with javascript tag)

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger, hyperledger-chaincode, chaincode

I'm just playing for a demo with Hyperledger Fabric 2 test-network example:

[Github repo link](https://github.com/hyperledger/fabric-samples/tree/master/test-network)

[Hyperledger Doc](https://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/latest/test_network.html)

I'm having issues deploying chaincode to the test network, with Javascrip tag, executing the command below:

**`./network.sh deployCC -ccl javascript`**

The ERROR I'm getting is the following:

```
Chaincode definition approved on peer0.org1 on channel 'mychannel' failed
Deploying chaincode failed
```

The result of the log is as follows:

```
alex@alex:~/hl-fabric/fabric-samples/test-network$ ./network.sh deployCC -ccl javascript
deploying chaincode on channel 'mychannel'
executing with the following
- CHANNEL_NAME: mychannel
- CC_NAME: basic
- CC_SRC_PATH: NA
- CC_SRC_LANGUAGE: javascript
- CC_VERSION: 1.0
- CC_SEQUENCE: 1
- CC_END_POLICY: NA
- CC_COLL_CONFIG: NA
- CC_INIT_FCN: NA
- DELAY: 3
- MAX_RETRY: 5
- VERBOSE: false
Determining the path to the chaincode
asset-transfer-basic
+ peer lifecycle chaincode package basic.tar.gz --path ../asset-transfer-basic/chaincode-javascript/ --lang node --label basic_1.0
+ res=0
Chaincode is packaged
Installing chaincode on peer0.org1...
Using organization 1
+ peer lifecycle chaincode install basic.tar.gz
+ res=0
Chaincode is installed on peer0.org1
Install chaincode on peer0.org2...
Using organization 2
+ peer lifecycle chaincode install basic.tar.gz
+ res=0
Chaincode is installed on peer0.org2
Using organization 1
+ peer lifecycle chaincode queryinstalled
+ res=0
Query installed successful on peer0.org1 on channel
Using organization 1
+ peer lifecycle chaincode approveformyorg -o localhost:7050 --ordererTLSHostnameOverride orderer.example.com --tls --cafile /home/alex/hl-fabric/fabric-samples/test-network/organizations/ordererOrganizations/example.com/orderers/orderer.example.com/msp/tlscacerts/tlsca.example.com-cert.pem --channelID mychannel --name basic --version 1.0 --package-id --sequence 1
+ res=1
Chaincode definition approved on peer0.org1 on channel 'mychannel' failed
Deploying chaincode failed
```

Comment: Is it correct to execute the `./network.sh up createChannel` command? Can the network build command tell you what to use?

Comment: I just tried it for the first time and it works fine...

Comment: @myeongkilkim I already executed ./network.sh up createChannel command, before trying to install the chaincode.

Comment: I work so well. coud you give me logs? below commands, `docker ps -a`, `docker logs <your_peer_container>`

Comment: I am also facing the same error.